# MySQL getting coupons that have NOT been used

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 MySQL tables which hold information about a user, coupon information and if a user has used a coupon. Something like this: 
User Table

```
+----------+-------------+
| User_ID  | Name        |
+----------+-------------+
|    1     | Sarah J     |
|    2     | John Smith  |
|    3     | Osman Lee   |
+----------+-------------+
```

Coupon Table

```
+----------+-------------+
| Coupon_ID| Title       |
+----------+-------------+
|    1     | Free Stuff  |
|    2     | 50% Off     |
|    3     | $5 off $25  |
+----------+-------------+
```

And Redeemed Table

```
+----------+---------+----------+
| Coupon_ID| User_ID | Redeemed |
+----------+---------+----------+
|    1     |    1    |   yes    |
|    2     |    2    |   yes    |
|    1     |    2    |   yes    |
+----------+---------+----------+
```

Basically I want this output for every user: 
Sarah J:    Coupons 2 & 3 
John Smith: Coupon 3 
Osman Lee:  Coupon 1, 2 & 3

I tried using joins but no luck so far. Any suggestions? [For Sarah]

```
SELECT Coupons.coupon_id, Coupons.title
FROM Coupons
LEFT JOIN Redeemed ON Redeemed.coupon_id != Coupons.coupon_id
WHERE Users.user_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to generate all the rows and then remove the ones that exist -- a `cross join` and a `left join`:

```
select u.user_id, c.coupon_id as not_used_coupon_id
from coupons c cross join
     users u left join
     redeemed r
     on r.coupon_id = c.coupon_id an dr.user_id = u.user_id
where r.coupon_id is null;
```

You can add the `where` clause on the *users* tables.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that every relation between coupon and user is in the Redeemed Table.
If that is the case then you can simply use an `inner join` like this:

```
SELECT Coupons.coupon_id, Coupons.title
FROM Redeemed r
INNER JOIN Users u ON 
u.User_ID = r.User_ID 
INNER JOIN Coupons c ON 
c.Coupon_ID = r.Coupon_ID
where r.Redeemed = 'No'
```

I assume that the value Redeemed can be no for coupons that have not been Redeemed.

I hope that helps...